# Variables within the printf

Tags: bash, variables, printf

Using bash I need to print some txt file which actually is another python script consisted of some tittles moved into the variable (t) within the main script

```
t="test"

printf "import pymol
cmd.load("${t}.pdb")" > ./script.py
```

the problem that the resulting script.py looks exactly like what I've defined in my main script

```
import pymol
cmd.load("${t}.pdb")"
```

so how I can to past correctly value of 't' within the resulted script.py?

```
import pymol
cmd.load("test.pdb")"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a placeholder in the format string:

```
printf 'import pymol\ncmd.load("%s.pdb")' "$t"
```

`%s` specifies that a string value will be inserted. It is not considered good practice to use variables within the format string; they should be passed as additional arguments to `printf`.

I have also fixed your quotes and used a newline `\n` rather than defining the string over two lines. It is always good practice to double quote your variable expansions, e.g. `"$t"`.

An alternative in this case would be to use a heredoc, which you may prefer:

```
t='test'
cat <<EOF >script.py
import pymol
cmd.load("${t}.pdb")
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t="test"

printf "import pymol 
cmd.load('$t.pdb')" > script.py
```

You can do like you do when you a value `echo $smth` using just `$`. Mind the absence of `./` when writing to a file. We execute a file by adding a dot and a slash but we don't write to it like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
t="test"

printf "import pymol 

cmd.load("$t.pdb")" > script.py
```